# How to make yes/no switch in flutter

Tags: flutter, user-interface, toggle, uiswitch

How to make a yes/no toggle switch in a flutter. I want the design as shown below.
[image: design]

Answer (score 2):

Try below answer hopeful its help to you:

You must used for [toggle_switch](https://pub.dev/packages/toggle_switch) package . add this or any version `toggle_switch: ^1.2.0` of package in your pubspec.yaml file.

Then `import 'package:toggle_switch/toggle_switch.dart';` this package in your dart file

Your Widget:

```
 Center(
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Text('Are You Married?'),
          SizedBox(
            width: 20,
          ),
          ToggleSwitch(
            initialLabelIndex: 0,
            totalSwitches: 2,
            labels: [
              'Yes',
              'No',
            ],
            onToggle: (index) {
              print('switched to: $index');
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
```

Your result screen like->[image]

Comment: Actually I need same design

Answer (score -1):

```
bool _switchValue=true;
```

in your dart file

```
CupertinoSwitch(
              value: _switchValue,
              onChanged: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  _switchValue = value;
                });
              },
            ),
```